# How can I restrict access to a folder from another admin user in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, file-permissions

I have Windows 10 with two admin users. I want to restrict user2 from accessing a folder of user1 and user2 should not be able tot changes the setting made to that restricted folder. Is it possible?

Comment: No; What you want is not possible.  As an Administrator they can take complete ownership of the directory.

Comment: Understood. The second user needs to have power to install programs but I wanted to restrict it from access some areas.  Is there away for a user to install programs without being admin?

Comment: You would have to grant that permission to that user group.  What permissions are required are well documented, and are sigificantly dependent, on what group polcies you have enabled/disabled (so I can't tell you which permissions you need to grant since I know nothing about your domain).

Comment: I am a novice at this. I just have a laptop which I need to borow to someone. So I created a new user. But he needs to install some programs for a project so he need rights to install. Any simple solution to this?

Comment: You will be unable to acomplish this on any version of Windows that runs on a laptop.  This would require a Active Directory domain at a minimum.  **An Administrator on a local installation of Windows, that does not have encorcement of group polciies, means they have complete and total control over that system.**

Comment: If you have concern about the laptop being modified, make a backup image, and after *loaning* (not *borrowing*) the notebook to your acquaintance, restore the image, deleting her or his changes.